# What part of speech is this "clean" word in the sentence?

Tags: adverbs, transitive-verbs

> To start off with, let me come clean, the Java logging ecosystem is messy.

This  sentence is quoted from [*Setting up logging*](https://xmlcalabash.com/docs/reference/logging.html) second
paragraph. Is the word *clean* an adverb? Or *come* is a transitive
verb?

Answer (score 2):

*Clean* is an adjective. *Come*, here, is in an archaic usage where it means "become". This usage remains in phrases like *come clean*, *come true* (as a wish or dream), and *come untied*.

Comment: Thanks, I have understood the usage of "come".  Is the sentence the same as "let me make it to come clean"?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The phrase *come clean* is a set phrase meaning to *fess up* -- the author is being slightly playful by approaching the criticism as if it is a confession.

Comment: What is the subject of this phrase "come clean"?

Comment: He's saying "I will admit that I consider the Java logging ecosystem to be messy".

Comment: @KateBunting, I don't care about what does he mean, but the phrase structure  and each word's part of speech.

Comment: _Let me come clean_ = _allow me to confess_. _Come clean_ is a phrasal verb.